# PDF forms get online content

Tags: javascript, pdf, web-scraping, adobe, acrobat

Would it be possible to use the inbuilt Javascript in adobe pdf forms to get contents/scrape a web page?

When I googled if Javascript could do this there where CSP errors,
but pdf forms does not have this as far as I know.

thanks,
g3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suspected, it is not possible to achieve this with Acrobat's Javascript extensions.

There are a number of third party tools that can convert a website to a pdf. If you also need to build a form, rather than just convert a webpage, you could write a program that would leverage a third party conversion tool, then build the form using Acrobat's [Interapplication Communication API reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf). If you're more comfortable with Javascript, you could even use the PDDoc's JSObject to build the form with Javascript.

Comment: Well bummer, I was going to make automatic power cards for a game called `Dungeons and Dragons` :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/index.html) tool to get the HTML Content of a website and save it to a PDF

Then you can simply run 
`wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf` to get the Content of Google.com and save it to the PDF "google.pdf".

Comment: Well, it's a pdf, not HTML

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Check out the methods of Net.HTTP found in the "[JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf)". You might find a more recent version of the reference [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html).